# How to Change the Dock Indicator Lights Color in Mac OS X only for an app that I'm using right know?

Tags: macos, dock, firefox

How to Change the Dock Indicator Lights Color in Mac OS X only for an app that I'm using right know?

I have 10 Firefoxes in my Dock with 10 different profiles, and sometimes I'm lost - I'm not sure which one of them I'm using right now.

So, maybe there is a way to show it somehow? Like some kind of software or I can just add some code like `Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p -SOMECOLOR`?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how it shows to you right now? What do you mean with changing the Dock indicator light? Different style/color? Generally speaking the Dock indicator is user-wide and has one purpose: to show you which app is loaded up. If you have alternative versions of apps and cannot tell the difference, why not rename the apps? Potentially you may need to change the name inside the Info.plist file inside each instance of the app using an editor capable to show you XML content.

Comment: @Phoenix thank you for your comment.
I run them by Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p
I just want  to somehow make it stand out from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dock indicator light does not differ between which app is in the foreground.

As a workaround, you could install a third party item called [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/) (for EUR 6.95 as of this writing) to show you the content of the window when hovering over the icon with the mouse (similar to how Windows' Aero Desktop does).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell different Firefox profiles apart (on a mac) then this is the add-on you'll want to install:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fosx-label/

Customizable dock icon badges that can hold whatever text you put in there + easy to configure too.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 add-ons that can be helpful. They both show the current profile name on the statusbar.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/

https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/whoami/